# Mutate row sum but only if NA count is 2 or less

Tags: r, sum, na, dplyr, rowwise

I'm trying to mutate a new variable (sum) of 5 columns of data but only if NA count across affected columns (v2 to v6) is 2 or less otherwise return an NA. The code below sums only where there are no NA's. Help appreciated.

```
df <- data.frame(v1=c("A","B","C","D","E","F"), v2=c(4,NA,5,6,NA,NA), v3=c(7,8,9,NA,NA,NA),
                 v4=c(NA,3,5,NA,1,4), v5=c(NA,3,5,NA,1,NA), v6=c(NA,3,5,NA,1,4))
df
library(dplyr)
df = df %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(sum(v2, v3, v4, v5, v6))
df
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In base R, we can use `rowSums` twice, 1st to count sum of values in each row and second to count number of `NA`'s in R.

```
ifelse(rowSums(is.na(df[-1])) <= 2, rowSums(df[-1], na.rm = TRUE), NA)
#[1] NA 17 29 NA  3 NA
```

Using `dplyr` row-wise you can do this as :

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(col = ifelse(sum(is.na(c_across(v2:v6))) <= 2, 
                      sum(c_across(v2:v6), na.rm = TRUE), NA))

# A tibble: 6 x 7
#  v1       v2    v3    v4    v5    v6   col
#  <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1 A         4     7    NA    NA    NA    NA
#2 B        NA     8     3     3     3    17
#3 C         5     9     5     5     5    29
#4 D         6    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
#5 E        NA    NA     1     1     1     3
#6 F        NA    NA     4    NA     4    NA
```

Shortened the code using `ifelse` suggestion from @rpolicastro.

Comment: You can do everything in one mutate. `mutate(rowsum=ifelse(sum(is.na(c_across(!v1))) > 2, NA, sum(c_across(!v1), na.rm=TRUE)))`. This can probably be simplified more too.

Comment: Thanks, I updated the answer implementing your suggestion.